# How do I generate alpha-amylase and peptidase to produce oat milk?

Tags: milk

In extension of this [question](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/how-do-i-make-oat-milk/2825#2825), I want to know if I can generate the enzymes used to make oat milk (alpha-amylase and peptidase) on my own. It doesnt sound charming to me buying enzymes which are grown in biotechnological process.
I don't necessarily want to generate the isolated enzymes. Also amylase of malted barley or rye is good (if the goal of non slimy oat drink is reached).

**What I already tried:**

The usual recipe I use is [this one](https://www.deutschlandfunknova.de/beitrag/diy-hafermilch-so-lassen-sich-h%C3%A4ufige-fehler-vermeiden). But the milk is very slimy.

I added a small amount of [Kombucha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kombucha) to the oat flakes (fermenting it for a day), but the acid inside the Kombucha prevented the amylase from working. The taste was sweeter, but due to non metabolized sugar (I used herb tea and no black tea to feed my scoby).

**Whats worth a try (IMO):**

Adding flakes or crushed barley to the oat flakes and fermenting it for one or two days.

**What I will try next:**

I bought malted and milled rye for baking. I will set up oat flakes with water and a tablespoon of malted, milled rye and let it fermenting for a day and see if there is slime anymore.

**Does anyone have experience in producing enzymes for really self made oat milk?**

Comment: We were considering getting a machine that makes oatmilk, but the question of enzymes hasn't come up. The thread you reference has a link for a German language company that supposedly sells the enzymes, if you speak German.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @PaulWalker. I posted the link on the referenced question, but i dont want to use enzymes, generated in a biotechnological process. Does it work with the milk machine without enzymes? Which machine do you consider? I can imagine that it can work without enzymes cause the fermenting generates the enzymes. But you need time and the the right temperature for it.

Comment: We are still researching the machines, so don't have one yet. None have mentioned adding enzymes.